# Try catch for laravel is not working for duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using below code in laravel controller. And getting duplicate error for `username` but I need to handle it by try-catch. This code is not working.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Response;
use DB;

class StaffController extends Controller
{
    public function saveMember(Request $request){
        $errormsg = "";
        $result = false;
        try{
            $result = DB::table('members')->insert(
                    [
                        'username' => $request->username,
                        'phone' => $request->phone,
                        'status' => 1
                    ]
                );
        }catch(Exception $exception)
        {
            $errormsg = 'Database error! ' . $exception->getCode();
        }
        return Response::json(['success'=>$result,'errormsg'=>$errormsg]);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error, which I need to handle by try and catch

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test1' for key 'username'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: added In my question, error which I am getting

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to make Exception as global,

1. Either by using.

   ```
   use Exception;
   ```

and then use

```
catch(Exception $exception)
```

2. Or by using

   ```
   catch(\Exception $exception)
   ```

Instead of this

```
catch(Exception $exception)
```

Comment: Why does this work?  I.e. why is catch(Exception $exception) failing to catch the exception?

Comment: @JohnLittle : Are you able to catch error with `catch(Exception $exception)` without using `use Exception;` at the top ? Or you are pointing to any other thing ?

Comment: I was trying just "catch(Exception $exception)" without "use Exception". I changed it to "catch(\Exception $exception)" and it worked. I would have assumed that if Exception was not resolved, it would have thrown an error when it parses the try/catch?  Is \Exception clarifying the namespace? Is \ not default?

Answer (score 4):

you can easily avoid this try & catch block by first validating the uniqness of the username against the desired column in your db table. you can do it with your $request object or (better) by setting a custom Request class that will do this validation before excecution the controller method.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Yes, I will apply you suggestion later, but my question was why try-catch is not working, although it solved, thanks for your ans.

Comment: Even if i really like Laravel, i think using try/catch and an exception to detect possible duplicate is the most robust solution, hands down. Using a validation is cool and will prevent the issue in most case but you need to think about concurrency with a lot of connections and users. Even if it's unlikely shit can happen... Or someone might just try to make it crash using that kind of  tricks.

Comment: This approach creates a *race condition*. The only certain way to avoid that is to use a transaction that wraps both your validation check and the insert/update.

Answer (score 0):

according to this sample:

```
public function store(ServiceStoreRequest $request, int $id)
{
    $service = new Serviceable();
    $service->package_id = $id;
    $service->fill($request->all());
    try {
        $service->save();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return response(array(
            "code"=> 409,
            "error"=>"duplicate " . $exception->getMessage()));
    }
    return response($service);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data       = $request->all();
        $user       = Auth::user()->id;
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            Company::Save($data,$user);
            BankBranch::updateBranch($data,$user,$id);
            DB::commit();
            $status = true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            var_dump('Exception Message: '. $e->getMessage());
            var_dump('Exception Code: '. $e->getCode());
            var_dump('Exception String: '. $e->__toString());
            DB::rollback();
            $status = false;
        }
    }
```